# Autolayout issues not printed in console output

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm setting up layout from code. For some reason autolayout issues (conflicting constraints, missing constraint) are not printed at all to console output. 
Statements printed using print() function are printed correctly.

Any idea how to fix this problem? Setting up layout from code is really problematic without this output.

Version of Xcode: 9.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Missing constraints are *never* printed to the console. Only conflicting constraints are. I have no idea why you're not seeing those, if you have conflicting constraints. But in any case you can check your constraints in a much better way: run the app, get into the situation you want to check, and then switch to Xcode and choose Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy. If there are layout issues, they will be clearly called out.

Comment: There are also ways to use code to check for missing constraints (ambiguous layout) in code, i.e. with your own print statement. But the View Debugger is very clear.